# Deference a pointer to a struct and clone it

Tags: go

Please ignore that this seems like a bad idea, is bad style, etc.

The main issue here is that `process()` gets a pointer to a struct of an unknown type passed in as `interface{}` and I need to clone the underlying struct.

The core issue is that I can't figure out how to deference the pointer, since its passed in as `interface{}`, so I can clone the underlying struct and return it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Value string
}

func main() {
    foo1 := Foo{"bar"}
    foo2 := process(&foo1)
    result := reflect.DeepEqual(foo1, foo2)
    fmt.Println(result) // how do I make this true?
}

// objective: pointer to struct is passed it, clone of underlying struct is returned
func process(i interface{}) interface{} {
    return clone(i)
}
```

Comment: what is `clone`? Why do you need `process` and `clone` just to assign a copy?

Comment: In the utility I’m working on, a function like process() gets a pointer to a struct, performs operations not shown here, and returns the copy.  clone() is a function that does a deep clone on the struct.

Comment: If your structure is a simple value like shown, then assignment is a "deep clone", so I don't understand what the purpose of `clone` is. If the structure is more complex, you need to show what that is, since a deep copy would be unique to that structure (unless you're using something that reflects over the values like `github.com/mitchellh/copystructure`)

Comment: The case I’m concerned about is a more complicated structure and I would clone it with something like copystructure.  The issue is that 'i' is actually a pointer.

Comment: Why pass a pointer if your just going to clone it?

Comment: If you're using something like copystructure, `i` being a pointer value isn't an issue, since the point of "deep copy" packages like that is to recursively de-reference and copy values.

Comment: I’ll try that then and get back!

Answer (score 0):

Using some reflection magic, I was able to get this to work.  Thanks, [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb), for all your help!  The code in this question is obviously contrived.  I need this functionality for a testing utility that takes "snapshots" of structs of any type at different stages before various mutations are applied.

```
...    
func process(i interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    if value.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        i = value.Elem().Interface()
    }

    return copystructure.Copy(i)
}
...
```